# Cypher Query fail while defining the relationship count

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Neo4j Version: 3.0.4

Objective of the below query is to eliminate duplicate bus service and bustop in a path, it work fine if i didn't provide the relationship count `-[r:CONNECTSWITH]->` but if the relationship count defined `-[r:CONNECTSWITH*..3]->` ,then its throwing

> Key not found: r

**Working:**

```
OPTIONAL MATCH p=(o:PORT{name:"busstop1"})-[r:CONNECTSWITH]->(d:PORT{name:"busstop2"})
WHERE ALL(r1 IN rels(p)
          WHERE 1 = size(filter(r2 IN rels(p) WHERE (r1.service = r2.service))))
AND ALL(n IN nodes(p) WHERE 1 = size(filter(m IN nodes(p) WHERE id(m) = id(n))))
RETURN p
LIMIT 10
```

**Not Working:**

```
OPTIONAL MATCH p=(o:PORT{name:"busstop1"})-[r:CONNECTSWITH*..3]->(d:PORT{name:"busstop2"})
WHERE ALL(r1 IN rels(p)
          WHERE 1 = size(filter(r2 IN rels(p) WHERE (r1.service = r2.service))))
AND ALL(n IN nodes(p) WHERE 1 = size(filter(m IN nodes(p) WHERE id(m) = id(n))))
RETURN p
LIMIT 10
```

**Work around Solution:**

```
OPTIONAL MATCH p=(o:PORT{name:"busstop1"})-[r:CONNECTSWITH*..3]->(d:PORT{name:"busstop2"})
WHERE ALL(r1 in rels(p)
          WHERE 1 = size(filter(r2 IN rels(p) WHERE (r1.service = r2.service)))) =
      ALL(n IN nodes(p) WHERE 1 = size(filter(m IN nodes(p) WHERE id(m) = id(n))))
AND ALL(r1 in rels(p)
        WHERE 1 = size(filter(r2 IN rels(p) WHERE (r1.service = r2.service))))
RETURN p
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: I have updated the question with work around solution by duplicating codition, providing optimized solution is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

*Aside: This feels like a neo4j bug. If you are encountering this with the latest neo4j version, you may want to submit a [neo4j issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues).*

As a possible workaround, since the query does not actually use the `r` identifier, try removing it from the query.

Comment: while try with out `r` it throws with random identifier `key not found:   UNNAMED41` . Created this issue in neo4j git hub too